# How to store date with only four digital format?

Tags: postgresql, date, psql, date-format

In postgresql the date format is  `yyyy-mm-dd` by default.

```
create table sample(
quant  int,year date);
```

The data file is stored `data.csv` in csv format such as:

```
quant,year
10,2019
12,2020
13,2021
```

Try to import it with :

```
copy  sample(quant,year) 
from  'data.csv' 
(DELIMITER ',', FORMAT 'csv', HEADER);
```

It encounter an error:

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type date: "2019"
CONTEXT:  COPY sample, line 2, column year: "2019"
```

It is the only way to set year's type as int?

```
create table sample(
quant  int,year int);
```

How can import the data.csv without rewrite year's type?

Comment: A year is not a date, so don't do that.

Comment: The value for the year only must be stored in numeric column (SMALLINT is enough). *How can import the data.csv without rewrite year's type?* Add fake month and day (for example, Jan 1).

Comment: If you only store a year, then you can't use the `date` data type. You have to use `int` or `smallint`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use an intermediate table in case you do not want to change the schema of the "sample" table, followed by dropping the intermediate table.
Below are the commands you can follow:

Original schema:

`create table sample(quant  int,year date);`

Intermediate schema (having one-to-one mapping with the datatypes present in CSV file):

`create table backup_sample(quant int, year int);`

Copy data from csv to intermediate table:

```
copy  backup_sample(quant,year) 
from  'data.csv' 
(DELIMITER ',', FORMAT 'csv', HEADER);
```

Followed by copying data to the original schema with the modification from the intermediate schema:

```
INSERT INTO sample (quant, year)
SELECT
 quant::INTEGER,
        to_date(CONCAT(year, '/1/1'), 'YYYY/MM/DD')
FROM backup_sample;
```

Post that you can drop the intermediate schema:

`DROP TABLE backup_sample;`

You can achieve the same in a transaction to avoid the voids.

Comment: Creating a new table to have the right format for export is a bad idea. Simply use an SQL query and the extract date function to get the year.

See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT and https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html for more details